# BoolToVisibilityConverter inside window.resources

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, converters

I have a list box that contains a label and a text box that the user can alter. The list box contents are defined in a data template (inside window.resources). I would like to add a border to each item in the list that has been changed using a booltovisibility converter.

I think I'm having trouble because I'm trying to set the converter inside window.resources.

Can somebody please point me in the right direction?

View Model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace MaintainPersonData
{
    public class MaintainPersonViewModel
    {
        public MaintainPersonViewModel(ObservableCollection<PersonViewModel> personList)
        {
        }

        public INotifyUser Notifier;

        private ObservableCollection<PersonViewModel> _personList;
        public ObservableCollection<PersonViewModel> PersonList
        {
            get
            {
                return _personList;
            }
            set
            {
                _personList = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("PersonList");
            }
        }

        private bool _changesMade;
        public bool ChangesMade 
        {
            get 
            {
                return _changesMade; 
            }
            set
            {
                _changesMade = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ChangesMade");
            }
        }

        private bool _hasErrors;
        public bool HasErrors
        {
            get { return _hasErrors; }
            set
            {
                _hasErrors = value;
                if (!_hasErrors)
                {
                    ErrorMessage = "";
                }
                OnPropertyChanged("HasErrors");
            }
        }
```

Xaml:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <conv:BoolToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVisibilityConverter"/>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="ListBoxItemTemplate">
        <Border BorderBrush="LightGreen" BorderThickness="2" Visibility="{Binding ChangesMade, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}">
        <Grid>
            <TextBox x:Name="PersonTextBox" Text="{Binding PersonName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
   </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
   <ListBox x:Name="PersonListBox" SelectionMode="Single" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Continue" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ListBoxItemTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding PersonList}">
        <!-- Code to highlight selected item (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15366806/wpf-setting-isselected-for-listbox-when-textbox-has-focus-without-losing-selec) -->
    </ListBox>

    <!-- BoolToVisibilityConverter works perfectly here -->
    <Label Name="ErrorLabel" Grid.Column="0" Foreground="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Visibility="{Binding HasErrors, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}" >
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ErrorMessage, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        </Label>
     </Grid>       
</Window>
```

And Finally, the converter:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace MaintainRegexData
{
    class BoolToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return (bool)value ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please specify what kind of "trouble" you're having

Comment: after each modify set your `ChangesMade` to True

Comment: `ChangesMade` should be defined per each `PersonViewMode` lt's because right now you will (or will not) add border to all items. Have you checked that `Convert` method from `BoolToVisibilityConverter`  is invoked? And last thing - there is nothing wrong with setting converter in window resources.

Comment: hold on. putting visibility on the border will make disappear the content. what you want is a binding on the `Thickness` and put a `Converter` on it to receive `visibility` and if it's not visible set thickness to 0

Comment: The problem is that although ChangesMade is false, every item in the list box is being given a border. @rraszewski could you please put this comment in an answer. You've just solved my problem! (The ChangesMade boolean was in the wrong place.)

Comment: and yes, @Franck, you're absolutely right. That was something I'd missed as well. I'll do that too.

Comment: @AnyaHope Just as an aside, you don't need to write your own Boolean-to-Visibility converter, there's [already one in the .NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thank you, the code I posted was from one that had been written previously by a colleague of mine so I didn't really write my own! Thanks for the reference though, that's very useful to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ChangesMade` should be defined per each `PersonViewMode` It's because right now you will (or will not) add border to all items. Have you checked that Convert method from `BoolToVisibilityConverter` is invoked? And last thing - there is nothing wrong with setting converter in window resources.

Answer (score 1):

first of all you Bind your `ItemsSource` to `PersonList` which it's Type is `ObservableCollection<PersonViewModel>` where `ChangesMade` include in `MaintainPersonViewModel` so you need to place your `ChangesMade` inside `PersonViewModel` class and make changes while `personName` Property changed.

and don't forget what @Frank said about Border.