# WPF ListBox with TextBox scroll to end of selected text when selecting text

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I have a ListBox using a DataTemplate (Grid with 2 TextBlock and 1 TextBox)

```xml
    <ListBox Name="lbHistory" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" MouseDoubleClick="LbHistory_MouseDoubleClick" Margin="10,0,0,0" ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource _ListBoxItemStyle}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>    
            <DataTemplate>    
                <Grid>    
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>    
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>    
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="130"/>    
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>    
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>    
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>    
                        <RowDefinition Height="20"/>    
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>    
                    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Direction}"/>    
                    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding TimeStamp, StringFormat=s}"/>    
                    <TextBox VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Message}" IsReadOnly="True" IsReadOnlyCaretVisible="True" BorderThickness="0"/>    
                </Grid>    
            </DataTemplate>    
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        ...
```

Styles to make selected item bold

```xml
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="_ListBoxItemStyle" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                        <Border Name="_Border"
                                Padding="2"
                                SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                            <ContentPresenter />
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    
                            <!-- This removes the blue selection around the item which looks ugly with the white text box
                            Also sets the selected item to bold -->
                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                                <Setter TargetName="_Border" Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                            </Trigger>
    
                            <!-- This ensures that a clicked textbox passes the selection event through -->
                            <!-- Deselects the row. Better solution see below -->
                            <!--<Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="true" />
                            </Trigger>-->
    
                            <!-- This ensures that a clicked textbox passes the selection event through -->
                            <!-- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15366806/wpf-setting-isselected-for-listbox-when-textbox-has-focus-without-losing-selec/15383435#15383435 -->
                            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="PreviewGotKeyboardFocus">
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ListBoxItem.IsSelected)">
                                            <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="True"/>
                                        </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </EventTrigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
```

The TextBox can be larger than the ListBox. The ListBox then shows a scrollbar. This works fine.
When I click into the TextBox and select the text via mouse (Click and hold LMB, move mouse to the right), the ListBox automatically scrolls to the right so that the end of the selected text is visible.
How can I achieve the same behavior using keyboard's curser keys (with or without holding shift key to select)?

Due to DataTemplate, TextBox can not be assigned to a member variable (Name="myTextBox" does not create a member variable)

Using TextBox's SelectionChanged and ListBox.ScrollIntoView(sender) does not work as the TextBox is already in the view

Comment: You would have to use the TextBox own ScrollViewer to scroll the text/content.

Comment: TextBox exposes a related API. For example it defines methods like `LineDown` , `LineRight`,, `BringIntoView` or `ScrollToEnd` to name a few.

Comment: @BionicCode The scroll that gets invoked when selecting by mouse is the scroll of the ListBox. The same should be achieved when selecting by cursor keys

Comment: So if the TextBox is in the viewport and you want to scroll the ScrollViewer of the ListBox programmatically, you must get the ScrollViewer and scroll horizontally. You can use the VisualTreeHelper to search the visual tree of the ListBox for the ScrollViewer.