# How to latch the SelectedIndex on a WPF listbox when a child control has focus

Tags: c#, wpf

I currently have

```
<Style x:Key="ListboxItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="True" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

However the problem is that the SelectedIndex returns to `-1` when I
give some other control on the UI focus. The behaviour I am looking
for is that the `ListBoxItem` is selected when a child gains focus
but does not reset when the child loses focus.

Comment: Isn't [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3023041/1834662) what you're looking for? you could wrap the handler into a behavior if you do not want a code-behind event handler and need notifications via bindings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the `Trigger` with an `EventTrigger` then `IsSelected` isn't returning to original state:

```
<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="PreviewGotKeyboardFocus">
    <BeginStoryboard>
        <Storyboard>
            <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsSelected">
                <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame Value="True" KeyTime="0:0:0" />
            </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
    </BeginStoryboard>                          
</EventTrigger>
```

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.eventtrigger.aspx)

> Unlike Trigger, EventTrigger has no concept of termination of state, so the action will not be undone once the condition that raised the event is no longer true.

PS: I have tried this for `SelectionMode="Single"` only.

Comment: Yeah this works but it's totally nasty that you can't use property setter notation within an EventTrigger and have to resort to storyboard. I think some kind of attached behavior could wrap this pattern up.